# pandas series/frame quantile function taking multiple probabilities?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to call frame.quantile (or series.quantile) and provide a list of probabilities? It looks like this is simply an omission in the code as it relies on scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile which takes both a list of probabilities and an axis argument.

```
In [10]: df = pandas.DataFrame(randn(100,10))

In [11]: df.shape
Out[11]: (100, 10)

In [12]: df.quantile().shape
Out[12]: (10,)

In [13]: df.quantile(q=array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-0e8c5e9629fc> in <module>()
----> 1 df.quantile(q=array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
....
```

Compare to:

```
scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile(randn(100,10), per=[0.1, 0.2], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write one:

```
def quantile_list(df, quantiles):
     return type(df)({q: df.quantile(q) for q in quantiles})
     # this will work for both Series and DataFrames

quantile_list(df, array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3]))
```

Example use:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(randn(100,10)

In [12]: quantile_list(df, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
Out[12]:
        0.1       0.2       0.3
0 -1.170263 -0.873469 -0.646108
1 -1.022404 -0.710545 -0.475673
2 -1.052089 -0.624228 -0.284597
3 -1.258572 -0.768058 -0.511088
4 -1.326680 -0.711250 -0.496603
5 -1.251355 -0.927114 -0.585490
6 -1.288566 -0.855460 -0.554957
7 -1.434426 -1.021975 -0.675071
8 -1.151979 -0.705312 -0.465302
9 -1.228328 -0.836559 -0.450415

In [13]: quantile_list(df[1], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
Out[13]:
0.1   -1.022404
0.2   -0.710545
0.3   -0.475673
dtype: float64
```

Comment: +1 for ``type(df)`` as a constructor. Wish I'd thought of that or seen it a year ago!

Comment: Just use the built in quantiles in scipy.stats.mstats or pencentile in numpy.

Comment: @mathtick lol, considering the OP is using it in their question!!